# List contacts only for "My Contacts" group using Google Contacts API v3

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-contacts-api

Whenever I list my contacts using Google Contacts Api v3, the query returns **480 results**, while I just have **269 contacts** on *My Contacts* list.

I'm trying to filter them so it only shows contacts from *My Contacts* group, so I'm querying for the groups that I have, to check *My Contacts* group Id. I'm using this query for that purpose:

https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/default/full/

The problem is that it returns all groups except *My Contacts* group.

Right now I'm struggling for help... How can I get My Contacts group id so I can filter the contacts query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the problem.

I was not passing the `&v=3.0` parameter to the query, so the final query I had to use was:

https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/default/full/?v=3.0

Comment: I am not able to get contacts email/name from response.
Request: https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/default/full/?v=3.0&alt=json&access_token=<<token>>&max-results=4000

Comment: This will return the groups but how did you end up getting all the contacts for that group?

Comment: Thanks a lot !  This fixes a lot of things